# Android: Using notifyDataSetChanged to update listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a listview which I want to edit from a dialog box. I've read from googling that I need to notifyDataSetChanged() on the listview, however when I try to do this I get an error:

```
The method notifyDataSetChanged(View) is undefined for the type ListView
```

[image]

My listview is set originally at the top of my code with just a:

```
ListView listView;
```

It's then set in a routine on the onload

```
public void loadItems(){
    //Removed - just getting the data

     int rowCount;       
     rowCount = mCategory.size();

     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);


     int[] colors = {0, 0xFFFF0000, 0}; 
     listView.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colors));
     listView.setDividerHeight(1);
     listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());

     listView.setClickable(true);
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

          loadPopup(mDescription.get(position).toString(), mCountList.get(position).toString(), mTemplatecode.get(position).toString());
       }
     });
     //Removed - Tidying up
}
```

The dialog box that is loaded on the onlick has a simple interface, a minus button, a plus button, a text box and a go button. The number in the textbox is changed which does a db call. When the dialog box closes I want it to refresh the listview behind to reflect the new change. I.e. basically re-run the loadItems() routine again.

This is what happens when you click the go button on the dialog. I'm obviously putting the notifyDataSetChanged in the wrong place as it wont even run.

```
 btnGo.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addAsset(v, AssetDesc, txt.getText().toString(), templateCode);
            listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
            loadItems();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

Custom adapter:

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mDescription.size();
    }
@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    LayoutInflater inf=getLayoutInflater();
    View v=inf.inflate(R.layout.noncriticalasset, arg2,false);

    TextView tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtOption);
    TextView tvCount=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCount);

    tv.setText(mDescription.get(arg0).toString()); 
    tvCount.setText(mCountList.get(arg0).toString()); 

    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter, not the ListView itself.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, by on the adaptor what do you mean? Appreciate the help

Comment: Keep a class reference of 'adapter = new CustomAdapter();` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(); ?

Comment: Do you mean the data adapter? As you can see it's loading it from listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter()); - which I'll add to my code abo ve

Comment: `adapter = new CustomAdapter()` instead of `listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter());`.  Then do `listView.setAdapter( adapter );`.  When you update the data, do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could ignore that extra code and just do `listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` when the data changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far. The second way is more preferable to me, however I'm stillgetting a The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

Comment: I've done it the first way, added the adaptor up the top, then referenced that. However it's still not refreshing the data

Comment: That's probably an issue with how you're storing/updating the data itself.  It would probably be best to make a new question for that and include the code that handles the data.